# Create and update a MapType column in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, cosine-similarity

I want to create a maptype column in pyspark than contains keys (string) and values (frequency of the strings) to an existing dataframe. For each row, the values will accumulate based on the occurrences of the keys.

[image: What I want it to be]

As you can see, the list of unique keys is fixed in length (6 in this case, from A to F). And the frequency of the keys in the *Strings* is accumulated within groups. Each group will starts out with 0 for each key. The *index* column is there to dictate which entry comes first as I need this to be in chronological order. I will extract and use the values in the Map_accumulated column as vectors for cosine distance calculation later. My understanding is that it is doable to extract the values and use them, similar to Python's dictionary.

So far, I have a dataframe with the first three columns and a list (fixed length) of all keys in string set up. I converted the list into a dictionary with 0 as the starting value.

[image: existing dataframe]

and

```py
    level_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    level_dict = {i:0 for i in level_list}
```

In the actual data, level_list is very long (300+) and that's why I felt I needed to create list/dictionary with 0 starting value first before I integrate it into the pyspark dataframe.

I wish I could go into further detail of what I have tried. But I really have no idea what I'm doing. I've been trying to use ChatGPT to help with the code but I couldn't figure it out.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, create_map
from itertools import chain

    my_list = list(chain(*level_dict.items()))
    my_map = create_map(my_list).alias("map")
    df = df.withColumn("map", my_map)
```

The code above was AI generated but I clearly didn't specify the prompt correctly as I got this error:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0 of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Any help is truly, truly appreciated. I have some experience doing data analysis in R, but trying to learn Python and Spark (along with, I guess, SQL) at the same time is very confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry for using images of the dataframe instead of the actual ones. SO editor insisted that there were codes that weren't formatted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to `explode` the `Strings` list and pivot the dataframe to have `Strings` as column and count as the value of the columns. Next, use a window function to do a cumulative count for all element in `level_list`. Then, aggregate the count values into MapType.

```
# import it as alias F, Because I will use sum from the python built-in later.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

level_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
w = Window.partitionBy('Group').orderBy('Index')

df = (df.withColumn('Strings', F.explode('Strings'))
      .groupby('Group', 'Index')
      .pivot('Strings')
      .count()
      .fillna(0)
      .select('*', *[F.sum(x).over(w).alias(f'{x}_cum') for x in level_list]))
```

This will result in

```
+--------+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   Group|Index|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|A_cum|B_cum|C_cum|D_cum|E_cum|F_cum|
+--------+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Appricot|    1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  0|    0|    1|    1|    0|    1|    0|
|Appricot|    2|  2|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|    2|    2|    2|    1|    1|    0|
|   Peach|    1|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|   Peach|    2|  1|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|    2|    1|    0|    1|    0|    1|
|   Peach|    3|  1|  0|  0|  2|  0|  1|    3|    1|    0|    3|    0|    2|
+--------+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

If you are missing any A-F columns, you can add them by `df.withColumn('X', F.lit(0))`.

To aggregate into MapType,

```
# **This sum is python's function not pyspark's function.
df = df.select('Group', 'Index', 
               F.create_map(*sum([[F.lit(x), F.col(x)] for x in level_list], [])).alias('Map'),
               F.create_map(*sum([[F.lit(x), F.col(f'{x}_cum')] for x in level_list], [])).alias('Map_acc'))
```

#### Update

I am not sure if this is any better in performance, but I tried without exploding.

```
# This is required to map_concat on the same key.
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy', 'LAST_WIN')

def count_strings(acc, x):
    new_val = F.coalesce(acc[x] + 1, F.lit(1))
    return F.map_concat(acc, F.create_map(F.lit(x), F.lit(new_val)))

df = df.withColumn('Map', F.aggregate('Strings', F.create_map().cast("map<string,int>"), count_strings))
```

Result

```
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------------------------+
|Group  |Index|Strings        |Map                             |
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------------------------+
|Peach  |1    |[A, B]         |{A -> 1, B -> 1}                |
|Peach  |2    |[A, D, F]      |{A -> 1, D -> 1, F -> 1}        |
|Peach  |3    |[D, F, D, A]   |{D -> 2, F -> 1, A -> 1}        |
|Apricot|1    |[B, C, E]      |{B -> 1, C -> 1, E -> 1}        |
|Apricot|2    |[B, C, A, A, D]|{B -> 1, C -> 1, A -> 2, D -> 1}|
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do I have to define 'li' in `for x in li`? The first time I ran it as-is, Databricks says 'li' is not defined. So I used level_list in that place. Then Databricks says 'w' is not defined. Do I have to import window function for it?

Comment: sorry my bad.  `li` should be `level_list` and the line that define `w` was left on the latter part of the code block. I updated the answer, so please try again.  You need to import Window from `from pyspark.sql import Window`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the list is now too long or what. Your edited code works, but it got suck on one (maybe more, I have no idea) on one of the strings in the list. 

'[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `2918` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`2718`, `2908`, `2910`, `2911`, `2912`];...' (It's very long)

Comment: If level_list is very long, I think this solution has performance hit. I can think another approach later, but in the mean time the latter error seems maybe you are missing the instruction written here: "If you are missing any A-F columns, ". Does this fix your issue and after the fix, how long does it run for?  Also, how long is your `level_list`?

Comment: The list is very long (334). I didn't even think about exploding it because of this reason. I also don't know why it stuck at that particular level (that "2918" level is the 251st level, is there a limit on how many rows/columns you can explode on pyspark??). I checked the list if there were any strings missing but everything seems to be there. 

I haven't tried to add any columns because the main code chunk couldn't finish it. So I have no idea if there's any columns missing. (If I understand this right, again I truly appreciate your help and patience).

Comment: Hi, I updated an approach without exploding the list. I only tried the first half of your question but could you try it and see if this is any better in performance or not. If this succeeds, this could be a valid solution to pursue the latter half of your question.  If you still have issues, please include your env info (Where you are running the Spark, how many workers, what is the driver/worker memory sizes, etc)?

Comment: This works the way you intended.  And unless I use '.display()' it works lightening fast! Thank you very much! The problem I have is then it doesn't refer to the 'fixed list' (level_list) that I have. So it generates the map for what's in the 'Strings' column only. 

I'm thinking about just create another column with another map but refer to the 'level_list' where all the values are 0, then combine the two columns where the values of the matching keys get added. Does that sound like a reasonable approach?

PS. The driver has 30.5GB RAM/4 cores and the worker has 61 GB RAM and 8 cores.

Comment: "unless I use '.display()' it works lightening fast!". If you don't have any action method, Spark won't actually evaluate(run) the code (please refer to Spark lazy evaluation). I intentionally didn't fill the values with 0 because it is memory intensive. Sure, I think you can combine with/without creating a new column with `map_concat`. Maybe it is better to aggregate first then do combining.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last off-topic question: do you have any recommendations for resources i could learn from? I feel like I get lost in the sea of resources and I pick up bits from here and there but nothing has 'clicked' for me. I had never worked with data this size and my background in "coding" is mainly for statistical analysis using R.